# Extracting the title from a html page from certain sites

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract title of a web page from a particular site http://www.justdial.com with jsoup as follows:

```
    Document doc=jsoup.connect("http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Satkar-Veg-Restaurant-%3Cnear%3E-Sahakar-Nagar-Next-To-Talwalkars-Gym-Wadala/022P5318248_TXVtYmFpIFJlc3RhdXJhbnRz_BZDET").get();
    String title=doc.title();
    System.out.println("Title="+title);
```

It is giving me a title string which is even not anywhere in the source of that page but viewable in the browser. But for all the pages from different sites it is working properly.
So can anyone give what is the reason behind that and how to get the desired result in such cases. Thank you.

Comment: What title is it returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the user-agent header so the website returns the suitable html for you

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Satkar-Veg-Restaurant-%3Cnear%3E-Sahakar-Nagar-Next-To-Talwalkars-Gym-Wadala/022P5318248_TXVtYmFpIFJlc3RhdXJhbnRz_BZDET").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the title of a given page is being updated via Javascript, it won't be viewable in the source or scrapable by a script.

You can compare the original source with the generated source by using the "view generated source" menu item in webdeveloper tools